# Sigma algebra generated by SOT versus of sigma algebra generated by WOT

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $H$ be a non-separable Hilbert space. Let us denote $B_s$ ($B_w$), by the sigma algebra generated by the strong operator topology (weak operator topology) on $B(H)$.

Question: Is $B_s$ the same as $B_w$?

Comment: Having in mind the maps $B(H) \to H, A\mapsto Av$ (as a map sot-to-norm-topology and wot-to-weak-topology respectively), I think one should first think about whether the norm and the weak topology on $H$ generate the same $\sigma$-algebra. I don't think they do, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks for your interesting clue. Firstly, you have considered $B^{\tau}_0$, the sigma-algebra generated by the sub-basic neighborhoods which are different from the sigma algebra generated by the topology in this problem (it can be  shown that no bounded set is in $B^{\tau}_0$).   As your guess, I am positive. If $E$ is an ortonormal basis in $H$ then (it seems that) $E$ will no longer in the sigma algebra generated by the weak topology.